# Using merge.zoo to dynamically create variables in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop, zoo

I'm trying to create a function that automatically creates polynomials of a `zoo` object.  Coming from Python, the typical way to it is to create a list outside a `for` loop, and then append the list inside the loop.  Following this, I wrote the below code in R:

```
library("zoo")

example<-zoo(2:8)

polynomial<-function(data, name, poly) {

##creating the catcher object that the polynomials will be attached to
returner<-data

##running the loop
for (i in 2:poly) {

#creating the polynomial
   poly<-data^i
  ##print(paste(name, i), poly)  ##done to confirm that paste worked correctly##

##appending the returner object
merge.zoo(returner, assign(paste(name, i), poly))
}
return(returner)
}

#run the function
output<-polynomial(example, "example", 4)
```

However, when I run the function, R throws no exceptions, but the output object does not have any additional data beyond what I originally created in the `example` zoo object.  I suspect I'm misunderstanding `merge.zoo` or perhaps now allowed to dynamically reassign the names of the polynomials inside the loop.

Thoughts?

Comment: Try this: `ans <- do.call(merge, lapply(1:4, function(i) example^i))` or this: `ans <- zoo(poly(example, 4, raw = TRUE), time(example))` or this: `z <- lag(example, rep(0, 4)); ans <- z ^ col(z)`.  In each case follow it by setting the names: `names(ans) <- 1:4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for error in your code you are missing assignment of result from `merge.zoo` to `returner`. 
However, I think there is better way to achieve what you want.

```
example <- zoo(2:8)

polynomial <- function(data, name, poly) {

    res <- zoo(sapply(1:poly, function(i) data^i))
    names(res) <- paste(name, 1:4)
    return(res)
}

polynomial(example, "example", 4)
##   example 1 example 2 example 3 example 4
## 1         2         4         8        16
## 2         3         9        27        81
## 3         4        16        64       256
## 4         5        25       125       625
## 5         6        36       216      1296
## 6         7        49       343      2401
## 7         8        64       512      4096
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to do some more reading into `sapply`, but it works like a charm.